# Can you choose -1 as the multiplicative unit? And what is a positive number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, philosophy

If one starts with the cyclic group of integers and want to introduce multiplikation the ordinare choice of multiplicative identity is the generator 1. But since 1 and its inverse -1 is sort of the same in the cyclic group, there is an automorphism that exchange these it should be possible to use -1 as multiplicative unit? 
How can "a positive number" be defined? In the ordinary setting starting with the integers as a cyclic (additive) group it seems that once you choose the multiplicative unit there is a split in positive and negative numbers.
In what sort of structures does it make sense? For all Z/nZ it seems possible to do with one sort of representative, so for practical purposes we could do arithmetic on the whole number in Z/nZ with a sufficiently large n.

Comment: Note that $(-1)^2 = 1$, but $(1)^2 \neq (-1)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but if you choose (-1) as multiplicative unit and assume the ring axioms the multiplicative unit squared would be unchanged and its additive invers would change sign when squared? I mean the situation would be analogue to that when 1 is the multiplicative unit?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ the abelian group that exchanges $1$ and $-1$, but it doesn't respect multiplication: that is, it isn't an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ the ring, which has no nontrivial automorphisms.
2. Positivity comes from an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring), which in general neither exists nor is unique. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ does not have an order (compatible with its group structure).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I know about (1), but has this any bearing on whether you could choose (-1) as the multiplicative unit?
(2) shows then that at least a cyclic group need to på infinite to admit definition of positivity?

Comment: @Anders: 1) you could, but then you'd have to redefine multiplication as $-ab$, and I don't know why you'd want to do that. 2) yep.